# Use of callback functions in interactive GUI code

Tags: c++, callback

I am working on a GUI system and using https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin and I use callback functions to register keypress events.

eg.

```
// register the function using the funcPtr
pangolin::RegisterKeyPressCallback(' ', funcPtr); 

while(!pangolin::ShouldQuit()){
  // ...some code...
  // Run till window is closed
  // ...some code...
}
```

Based on the pangolin code [here](https://github.com/stevenlovegrove/Pangolin/blob/d484494645cb7361374ac0ef6b27e9ee6feffbd7/components/pango_display/src/display.cpp#L317) which implements `RegisterKeyPressCallback` and uses a global `context` which stores the function pointer and is defined as

```
__thread PangolinGl* context = 0;
```

**Question & Scenario** - We are registering our functionPtr in the callback function  `RegisterKeyPressCallback` and the while loop starts.
In the middle of `while loop` I press `pause`.
I would like to know if there is a background thread always running and listening to the thread running the while loop, so that when I press pause, it detects the key press.

In general I would like to know, in real time interactive use cases like above, we pass in a function pointer to a callback function **once** and is there a **background thread running in parallel**, so that it can detect the events.

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions or other non-C questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't a separate thread checking for keyboard inputs. Instead each operating system has its own implementation of handling windows and keyboard events. on Windows specifically the code has to [register a window class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexa), which indicates a field for a callback to handle window message events. Take a look at [Windows Message Loops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues) where each iteration of the window loop a call to GetMessage/PeekMessage and DispatchMessage is made for event handling.

In Pangolin/components/pango_window/src/display_win.cpp the class and keyboard callback function is registered before you, the user of the library gets to see the actual window.

```
void WinWindow::RegisterThisClass(HMODULE hCurrentInst)
{
    WNDCLASSA wndClass;
    wndClass.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WinWindow::WndProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hInstance = hCurrentInst;
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = className;
    if(!RegisterClassA(&wndClass)) {
        std::cerr << "RegisterClass() failed" << std::endl;
        CheckWGLDieOnError();
    }
}
```

The function ProcessEvents is where the actual message loop is occurring.

```
void WinWindow::ProcessEvents()
{
    static bool needs_init = true;
    if(needs_init) {
        RECT cRect;
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &cRect);
        ResizeSignal(WindowResizeEvent({cRect.right, cRect.bottom}));
        needs_init = false;
    }

    MSG msg;
    while (PeekMessageA(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            CloseSignal();
            break;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageA(&msg);
    }
}
```

This specifically `wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WinWindow::WndProc;` Is what deals with the windows messages. WndProc just returns to `LRESULT WinWindow::HandleWinMessages(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`

`WinWindow::HandleWinMessages` then checks if a keyboard message was processed by the window. If so, the library will perform a check to see which key was pressed and if the user registered a function callback for that specific key. And perform the callback.

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_KEYUP:
    {
        unsigned char key = GetPangoKey(wParam, lParam);
        if(key > 0) {
            KeyboardSignal(KeyboardEvent({
                afLastMousePos[0], afLastMousePos[1],
                KeyModifierBitmask(),
                (unsigned char)key, message == WM_KEYDOWN
            }));
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

`keyboardSignal(KeyboardEvent({` Is where your actual key press handling is done.

Keep in mind, the overview I gave is Windows specific. OSX, Unix, GNU have their own implementations which I imagine Pangolin deals with case by case.

Comment: So we are registering the function with the OS at the basic level, finally who calls the funcPtr ??

Comment: @Nitron_707 The library does under WM_KEYDOWN/WM_KEYUP event after you've registered your own callback for that specific key.